# WordPress Using wp_config.php variables in other PHP files to Connect to DB

Tags: php, database, wordpress, include, config

I have a simple php file that is connect to the wordpress DB and any thing that  want works fine. But I want to use the value from `wp_config.php` file from wordpress to connect my php file to DB. I tried this but it's not working

```
   <?php

require_once('wp-config.php');
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

And this is my default PHP file that works. This file is in a directory inside the WordPress project that I use inside the other template for a custom search.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password , $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Note: I change the important Data!
Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be using PDO to connect, but other than that, perhaps try using `constant("variable")` instead of trying to use the variables directly:

```
<?php
require_once('wp-config.php');
$conn = new mysqli(constant("DB_HOST"), constant("DB_USER"), constant("DB_PASSWORD"), constant("DB_NAME"));
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Finaly it works for me. I change the first line like this include '../../../wp-config.php';

Answer (score 2):

The same code works fine for me.

> Check the **wp-config.php** path and try to echo the constants and
>   check you have included the correct file before passing to `mysqli`

```
 echo DB_HOST;
 echo DB_USER;
 echo DB_PASSWORD;
 echo DB_NAME;
```

or you can use **wp-load.php** `include('/path/wp-load.php');`

```
include_once ('/path/wp-load.php');
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the defines the user sets in wp-config:

```
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Since your script is outside the Wordpress environment, try this:

```
require_once(path/to/wp-config.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to connect WP DB in other external application or in a template to get data from WP DB you can include wordpress file directly in your file.
using `wp-blog-header.php` will load complete wordpress into your current template and then you can use make use of it.

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOUR_WP_DIR/wp-blog-header.php';
global $wpdb; // wordpress database object
print_r($wpdb);
```

Content of **wp-blog-header.php**:

```
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    // Load the WordPress library.
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    // Set up the WordPress query.
    wp();

    // Load the theme template.
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

Comment: add this line `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` after `include_once`

Comment: how should I set the /YOUR_WP_DIR/?

Comment: of course you need to need to change it with your folder name which holding the wordpress files and folders

Comment: I change that but it give 503

Comment: did you add `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` after include ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167786/discussion-between-noman-and-nasser-ali-karimi).